# Selecting Vue Components with Nightwatch?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nightwatch.js

Nightwatch.js requires CSS or XPath selectors to find specific HTML elements.

When I use Vue Components, they are converted into regular HTML elements, so how can I write my Nightwatch tests to find them?